# npm package static file path issue in aspnet core & vue project running on docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, npm, webpack, .net-core

I develop aspnet core project width vue.js on docker. my projects use npm packages for example materials design icons. I have a problem at publish.

nginx working in front of my docker container and an address was given to me (for example: http://devlinux/**yourdocker**). Because when I publish the project, npm static file addresses the home directory but the files are under **yourdocker**

How can I export your static file addresses to

1. **yourdocker/dist/blabla.woff**
2. **yourdocker/dist/blabla.ttf**

when building npm files?

Comment: IS your nginx a separate docker container?

Answer (score 0):

Use docker [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) to point directory from your docker container to some directory on your file system.

Parameter **-v** allows you to create a new volume during a docker container run.

```
 docker run --name your-container-name -v /my/own/datadir:/dist/ -d your-image-name
```

After that you can see in the **/my/own/datadir** directory on your file sistem all files from **/dist** from the container, so you can serve that files by your NGINX.

Comment: I think I have misunderstood myself. when npm build css files I want to change file addresses on css file 

for example font-face url(/dist...) instead of url(/mypath/dist/..)

Comment: @Tugrul Ah, I see what you're saying. But it's slightly different. I'd suggest you use root paths in your HTML and serve all static from the root http://devlinux/ 
Does that make sense?